# Error al intentar enviar una peticion con fetch en vue

Tags: vue.js, go

Estoy realizando una aplicacion la cual consume una api desarrollada en go, lo que hace la api es un inicio de sesion la cual crea una cookie para el jwt, pero me estoy encontrando con un problema y es que al momento de realizar la peticion me genera un error el cual dice Unexpected end of JSON input, pero no entiendo porque genera ese error pues segun lo que me han dicho es por el json no se envia completo, pero ya realize unas verificaciones para saber si los datos llegan y lo hacen de forma correcta, el problema es que aunque en el front hecho por vue me genera el error, el back no lo hace, asi que he realizado la misma peticion por medio de postman y no genera ningun problema.
Este es mi codigo vue:

```
<script>
  import { ref } from '@vue/reactivity';
  export default {
    setup() {
      const email = ref('');
      const password = ref('');

      const submitForm = () => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/login`, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email.value,
            password: password.value,
          }),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });
      };

      return {
        email,
        password,
        submitForm,
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```

Este es mi codigo go:

```
func Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    var u model.User

    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&u); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "format incorrect of json", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    user, err := function.VerificationLogin(u.Email, u.Password)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    token, err := jwt.CreateToken(user)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "ups "+err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
        Name:     "token",
        Value:    token,
        Expires:  time.Now().Add(1 * time.Hour),
        HttpOnly: true,
    })
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```